# .toggle jQuery issue, while switching the library Version of jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This is the code working fine when I use : `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.mailing-form').toggle(
    function(){
        $('#mailing-list-box').animate({
            right: "0",
        }, 500);
    },
    function(){
        $('#mailing-list-box').animate({
            right: "-256"
        }, 500);     
  });
});
```

But when I chose to switch the version of my jquery with : `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>`

The `toggle` stops working.

Then I tried to wrap the `toggle` inside `click` event, the `mailing-list-box` div keeps coming back and forth multiple times.

```
('.menu-btn').click(function(e) {
    $('.menu-btn').toggle(
 function(){
  $('.timeline-box2').animate({
  left: "0",
  }, 500);
 },
function(){
 $('.timeline-box2').animate({
 left: "-300"
 }, 500);     
});
});
```

Comment: The way of using `.toggle()` to switch between functions on alternate clicks is [**deprecated since jQery 1.8 and removed in 1.9**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the same behaviour without the old `.toggle()` this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var box = $('.timeline-box2');
    $('.menu-btn').on('click', function() {
        // set the animation value depending on presence of class 'forward'
        var pos = box.hasClass('forward') && -300 || 0;
        box.toggleClass('forward'): // switch class 'forward' on/off at each click
        box.animate({left: pos}, 500);
    });
});
```

This way each click adds a new animation to the animation queue. That means if you click three times the box goes one time to `left=0`, then to `left=-300` and again to `left=0`. If you dont want to add the animations but on click interrupt the running one and go reverse use [**jQuery.fn.stop**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before animate:

```
        box.stop().animate({left: pos}, 500);
```